# JSR-303/JSR-349 message key in Spring MVC 4

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I have an application (Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate/JPA + MySQL + Maven integration example using annotations), integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration.

I have this property

```
 @Pattern(regexp = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$", 
            message = "{general.error.mail}")
    private String email;
```

But when there is an error I see the key in the page instead of the message itself

```
 {general.error.mail}
```

Comment: Where did you add the message key's value? Add your configurations and project structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a messages.properties file. Check [Spring MVC Form Validation Example with Bean Validation API](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api) as a tutorial.